Check if a column does not contain a list of strings
Is there a way to check if a column does not contain a list of strings? My goal is to figure out if there are any other type of patterns of string beside apple, banana, or orange in the FileNm column.
This doesn't work because it will still show columns that either have apple, orange or banana... the logic is flawed.
SELECT *
FROM dbo.File f
WHERE (CHARINDEX('apple', f.FileNm ) = 0
OR (CHARINDEX('orange', f.FileNm ) = 0
OR (CHARINDEX('banana', f.FileNm ) = 0)


change OR to AND?

I think that wouldn't work since it will look for filenm contains apple and orange and banana, which is not possible. It will contain only one of them, but not all.

No, that's not how it works, give it a spin.

Change from OR to AND
SELECT *
FROM dbo.File f 
WHERE (CHARINDEX('apple', f.FileNm ) = 0
    AND (CHARINDEX('orange', f.FileNm ) = 0
    AND (CHARINDEX('banana', f.FileNm ) = 0)

Could also write it like this
SELECT *
FROM dbo.File f
WHERE f.FileNm NOT LIKE '%apple%'
    AND f.FileNm NOT LIKE '%orange%'
    AND f.FileNm NOT LIKE '%banana%'

